# Extra char's added to end of file when read

Tags: c, file, io, operating-system, filesystems

I'm copying a file from linux to our file system, which we've successfully done however when the file is printed out there are extra characters at the end of the file. We think it has to do with memory allocation but we can't see how to fix it. Thank you for your help!

ACTUAL EOF: ∴ But no TM could possibly decide H, so M_o could not possibly exist.�}�0E�

CORRECT EOF: ∴ But no TM could possibly decide H, so M_o could not possibly exist.

```
void copyToFS(char *filePath, int currentDirectoryID)
{
    printf("Enter file path: ");
    scanf("%s",filePath);
    int node = assignNode(filePath, 0, currentDirectoryID);
    long int fileSize = getFileSize(filePath);

    FILE *file  = fopen(filePath, "r");

    printf("\nSize of : %ld", fileSize);

    char fileBuffer[fileSize];

    if (file != NULL) {
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fread(fileBuffer, fileSize, 1, file);

    } else {
        printf("Could not open file :(");
    }

    fclose(file);

    printf("\n%s", fileBuffer);

    assignBlocks(fileBuffer, node, fileSize/512);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, which obviously lacks some [MRE], and is probably off-topic on SO. Consider reading some [textbook on operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: you're missing space for the `'\0'` string terminator. Without the terminator `fileBuffer` is not a string, and printing it with `"%s"` invokes UB. Easy fix considering exclusively this `printf()` and terminator issue: `char fileBuffer[fileSize + 1] = {0};`

Comment: I followed exactly that but the {0} is throwing a "Variable sized object may not be initialized on the fileSize+1 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here. Let's start with the one concerning your question:

First, `fileBuffer` contains the contents of the file. That's ok, except that `printf()`'s `%s` expects a C-string, not the file's content. The difference is that a C string ends with the null byte `\0`.

Then, you have the assumption that the file contains text only. If the file is binary, and in particular if it contains a null byte somewhere, your print wouldn't work.

How to fix both issues: use `fwrite()`, which doesn't need the null byte: replace

```
printf("\n%s", fileBuffer);
```

with

```
fwrite("\n", sizeof("\n"), 1, STDOUT);
fwrite(fileBuffer, fileSize, 1, STDOUT);
```

Next, there's the assumption of the file size. If the file is 16MB in size, you'll try to allocate 16MB of memory on the stack, which will make your program crash.

How to fix: Either assert the assumption (`if (fileSize > SOMETHING) return;` or something similar), or allocate `fileBuffer` dynamically with `malloc()`.

Next, You aren't handling errors from `fread()`. If it failed, `fread()` will return 0.

How to fix: the bullet-proof way is to have a loop like:

```
while (!feof(file)) {
    fread(fileBuffer, fileSize, 1, file);
}
```

BUT, if your file can be big, `fread()` might only read part of it, and you need:

```
n = 0;
while (!feof(file)) {
    r = fread(fileBuffer + n, 1, fileSize, file);
    n += r;
}
```

Note that when you write the file (in `assignBlocks()`, I assume), if you use `fwrite()`, you also need a loop similar to that of `fread()`.

Last, I'm guessing that `fileSize/512` is supposed to be the number of sectors in the file, but if the file is 1500 bytes long, it will have 3 sectors, whereas `fileSize/512` would evaluate to 2.

How to fix: replace `fileSize/512` with `(fileSize + 511) / 512`.